# Relative Routing in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I am using Next JS.
Currently, my page is in the url

```
http://localhost:3000/project/613
```

Now, i want to push the page to

```
http://localhost:3000/project/613/time/123
```

Is there any way i can push relatively like `router.push('/time/123')`

Instead of entering the full URL `router.push('project/613/time/123')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While it's not *exactly* the same as relative routing you can prepend `router.asPath` to the relative part.

```js
router.push(`${router.asPath}/time/123`)
```

Meaning you don't need to explicitly set the beginning of the path.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work well. If you have a global navigation and navigate to this link and click on it again, you end with `/time/123/time/123` and so on.

Comment: @User If you have global navigation you'd want to have checks for the current path you are on, you can't just blindly use this.

Answer (score -3):

And for more options, if you don't want to do data fetching, you can add a shallow option. Check the docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing

Answer (score -10):

Yes. Just add `/` in the first:

```
router.push('/time/123')
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. It is already like what u have mentioned

Comment: This is not working...