# Next.js maintain route when navigating between screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js

I have the following problem in Next.js. Im building a Dashboard.
This would be somewhat the root route:

```
/dashboard/
```

Here you can select from different Stores to get to the Dashboard of the different stores.
Now when I click on one of the stores, this is my route:

```
/dashboard/store/%STORE_ID%/
```

%STORE_ID% is something like `3iHnkdnfkD` and I need it to communicate with my backend. Basically I use the ID as one of the keys to my database and wont to get it from the route when clicking on a page. Now, the route goes on... Lets say I have different products and each of them has an ID again:

```
/dashboard/store/%STORE_ID%/product/%PRODUCT_ID%
```

When navigating between these individual products, the %PRODUCT_ID% changes obviously and with it the route.
So, I have this route: `/dashboard/store/3iHnkdnfkD` as example;
The page would now consist of a table where I can click on the products to get a detailed page.
So I would use a NextLink and when I click on one of the products get its id to onclude in the route:

```
<NextLink href={`/dashboard/store/%STORE_ID%/product/${id}`}>
  <MyUnrelevantButton />
</NextLink>
```

Now, heres my problem: I need to know the `STORE_ID%` to navigate to the product, since otherwise, I would lose ref of the store. I know I would be able to retrieve the `STORE_ID%` from the route and than just pass it in again, but this is redundant and with more than a few NextLinks quite a lot of work. Is there any way to tell Next: *Use the route I have right know and just add /product/%PRODUCT_ID% to it*

Comment: You can use `window.location.href` to get the current route.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative Routing in Next JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69084689/relative-routing-in-next-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called dynamic routing in Next.js You will want to checkout [this example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/dynamic-routing) on how to accomplish this.

[The Next.js example repo](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples) as a ton of examples for common HOW-TO

Comment: Ok, basically I just figured out theres not really a shortcut, ty for the example tipp