# Next.js append to a slug/url with <Link> component

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have the following folder-based structure in my Next.js project.

```
/dashboard/[appid]/users/[userid]/user_info.tsx
```

I'm using Next.js's built in  component with `href={"user_info"}` on a user page. I expect the URL to dynamically point to `/dashboard/app_01/users/123123123/user_info`. However, I am currently redirected to the root level `/user_info` which does not exist.

The next.js react component looks like this:

```js
'use client';

import Link from 'next/link';
import React from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image';


type sidebarbuttonprops = {
    text: string,
    to?: string,
    id: string,
    active?: string,
    disabled?: string[],
    icon?: string,
    getButtonValue: (buttonid: string) => void
}

export const SideBarButton = ({ text, to: link, id, active, disabled, icon, getButtonValue }: sidebarbuttonprops) => {
    let buttonActive: boolean = id == active ? true : false;
    let buttonDisabled: boolean | undefined = disabled?.includes(id);
    const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        if (!buttonDisabled) {
            getButtonValue(id);
        }
    }

    return <Link className="sidebar-button" role='link' href={!buttonDisabled ? link! : ''} replace={false} onClick={handleClick}>
        <div className={`sidebar-button__container${buttonActive ? ' button_active' : ''}${buttonDisabled ? ' button_disabled' : ''}`} id={id}>
            <div className='sidebar-button__svg'>
                {icon != undefined && <Image src={icon!} alt="icon" width={25} height={25} />}
            </div>
            <div className='sidebar-button__text'>
                <span className='sidebar-button__span'>
                    {text}
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </Link>;
}
```

The generated HTML for the link looks like this:

```
<a class="sidebar-button" role="link" href="user_info">"[Some divs]"</a>
```

It is worth noting that when hovering over the link, the URL slug on the bottom part of the screen displays the correct URL of `/dashboard/app_01/users/123123123/user_info`. Despite this, clicking the link redirects me to an incorrect section of the site. If I click the link inside the DevTools, I am directed to the correct location.

TL;DR: how can I dynamically append the `user_info` to the current URL without the need to write down the entire URL?

Comment: Please append the actual code to the question that produces this outcome. Otherwise it is really hard to determine what causes it.

Comment: I think you have to create the whole URL. You may be able to create a custom link component that reads the current path from the router and appends the relative path (href) to the current path.

Comment: @FabioNettis Added the component code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative Routing in Next JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69084689/relative-routing-in-next-js)

Comment: @eten That was deprecated but I found usePathname does the same, I finally got what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself after eten highlighted a way to do it in next.js < 13.

In Next.js > 13, you need to use usePathname to get the current path and then you can append to it

```
 import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation';

 export default function Page() {
     const current_path = usePathname(); // current path
     ...
```